# Inactive ADUser Query and ADGroup Manipulation Encountering Issues

Tags: powershell

I'm trying (initially) to query ADUsers in a specific OU; identify those that are 90-days inactive; document their group memberships; make a note in the Description field that the account is being Disabled as of x-date; Disable identified accounts; and move disabled accounts to a "Parking" OU.

I've made notes in the Gist as well, but would appreciate any help getting the Group Membership piece working.

https://gist.github.com/rsmith7712/fdfe025d989508102044fdbbf5d3b9a8

Comment: not tested, but you might try something along these lines: http://pastebin.com/RrcKwqz0

Comment: @AnthonyStringer Looks like you fixed his script pretty well. You should write up an answer, and paste your code in that, not just a link to pastebin.

Comment: @AnthonyStringer - Thank you for the help!  When tested, it still wasn't pulling the ADUser Group Memberships and populating the CSV with that info, but the rest of the script worked BEAUTIFULLY.  I updated the Gist with v2, and added a Group Membership query that generates a separate CSV (not ideal but it captures the info).  Here's a question for you - Do you know of a way to limit the search scope of this 2nd query to the $xDays variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have not tested this, but it may be one way to solve your problem

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577369/inactive-aduser-query-and-adgroup-manipulation-encountering-issues

# Import Modules Needed
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Output results to CSV file
$LogFile = "C:\ZombieAcct_90dayRpt_n_Move.csv"

# Today's Date
$today = get-date -uformat "%Y/%m/%d"

# Date to search by
$xDays = (get-date).AddDays(-90)

# Expiration date
$expire = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

# Date disabled description variable
$userDesc = "Disabled Inactive" + " - " + $today

# Sets the OU to do the base search for all user accounts, change as required
$SearchBase = "OU=DEFINE,OU=DEFINE,OU=DEFINE,DC=DEFINE,DC=com"

# Sets the OU where accounts will be MOVED TO, change as required
$ParkingOU = "OU=30Days, OU=Disabled Accounts, OU=Domain Services, DC=DEFINE, DC=com"

# Pull all inactive users older than 90-days from a specified OU
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties memberof, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, WhenCreated, DisplayName -Filter {
    (LastLogonDate -notlike '*' -OR LastLogonDate -le $xDays) 
    -AND (PasswordLastSet -le $xDays) 
    -AND (Enabled -eq $True)
    -AND (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) 
    -AND (WhenCreated -le $xDays)
} | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_ -AccountExpirationDate $expire -Description $userdesc -WhatIf
    Move-ADObject $_ -TargetPath $ParkingOU -WhatIf
    $_ | select DisplayName, Name, SAMaccountName, PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, WhenCreated, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, @{n='Groups';e={(($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup).Name) -join '; '}}
}

$Users | Export-Csv $LogFile -NoTypeInformation

start $LogFile
```

Answer (score 0):

@AnthonyStringer - Took your script and tweaked it for the environment. Here's the (near) final script, Thank you for your help.

Issue still having:
- Collecting ADUser Group Memberships is still for everyone in the specified $SearchBase OU, instead of being able to JUST query those ADUser accounts who meet the $xDays variable.

Dev will continue on the Gist, but closing this question.
https://gist.github.com/rsmith7712/fdfe025d989508102044fdbbf5d3b9a8

```
# Inactive_ADUserRpt_n_Move_v3.ps1
#
# Git- rsmith7712, 2016-05-20
# 
# Contributors:
# @EricRocconi, @AnthonyStringer, 
# 
# Purpose of Script:
# 1. Query ADUsers in a specific OU and identify those that have been inactive for 90-days or more 
# 2. Document their Group Memberships 
# 3. Make a note in the user's Description field that the 'Account Disabled as of yyyy/mm/dd' 
# 4. Disable user's account 
# 5. Move the disabled user's account to a 'Parking' OU 
# 
# ############################################# 
# 
# Current Issues:
# 1. Unable to add in the functionality of querying and adding the results of Get-ADGroup and MemberOf to the original query 
#
# --> Need to add ability to constrain query to $xDays variable (IF unable to include results in Inactive Users query)
# 
# ############################################# 
# 


# Import Modules Needed
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Output results to CSV file
$LogFile = "C:\Inactive_ADUserRpt_n_Move_v3_USERS.csv"

# Today's Date
$today = get-date -uformat "%Y/%m/%d"

# Date to search by
#$xDays = (get-date).AddDays(-90)
#$xDays = (get-date).AddDays(-120)
$xDays = (get-date).AddDays(-365)

# Expiration date
$expire = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

# Date disabled description variable
$userDesc = "Disabled Inactive" + " - " + $today + " - " + "Moved From OU" + " - " + $SearchBase

# Sets the OU to do the base search for all user accounts, change as required
#$SearchBase = "OU=MIT, OU=Service Accounts, OU=Domain Services, DC=Domain, DC=com"
$SearchBase = "OU=Laptop, OU=IS, OU=Corporate Computers, DC=Domain, DC=com"


# Sets the OU where accounts will be MOVED TO, change as required
$ParkingOU = "OU=30Days, OU=Disabled Accounts, OU=Domain Services, DC=Domain, DC=com"


# Document Group Memberships and export to CSV 
# -- This will generate a CSV for ALL users in OU regardless of account status
# --> Need to add ability to constrain query to $xDays variable

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, MemberOf | % {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} | Select UserName, Groups | Export-Csv C:\ADUser_GroupMembership_Rpt.csv -NTI


# Pull all inactive users older than 90-days from a specified OU
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties memberof, PasswordNeverExpires, WhenCreated, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate -Filter {
    (LastLogonDate -notlike '*' -OR LastLogonDate -le $xDays)
    -AND (PasswordLastSet -le $xDays)
    -AND (Enabled -eq $True)
    -AND (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false)
    -AND (WhenCreated -le $xDays)
} |  ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_ -AccountExpirationDate $expire -Description $userdesc -WhatIf
    Move-ADObject $_ -TargetPath $ParkingOU -WhatIf
    $_ | select Name, SamAccountName, PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, WhenCreated, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, @{n='Groups';e={(($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup).Name) -join '; '}}
}

$Users | Where-Object {$_} | Export-Csv $LogFile -NoTypeInformation

#start $LogFile
```